# Template literal issue with chrome debugger

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, react-native

[image: Image of issue]

I'm having an issue with the chrome debugger. The text after a grave accent cause the debugger to work as needed. I can't easily add breakpoints.

Any known solution or a different syntax for this?

Comment: I don't understand what the problem is. What do you mean by "cause the debugger to work as needed"? Where do you want to add a breakpoint but can't?

Comment: The code won't debug properly. I can add a breakpoint. The execution stops but I can't view the variables. If I try to remove the grave accent the debugger skips some lines,

Answer (score 1):

I would just move the string creation to the line above the return and then put your break there.

```
renderScene() {
    const uri = `${facebook.oath_dialog}`;
    return (
        <WebView
          source={{ uri: uri }}
        />
    );
}
```